# How do I write a string literal that includes quotation marks?

Tags: python, string

I want to create a string with this exact text: `nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)`

Simply surrounding it with double quotes, like `"nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)"`, doesn't work:

```
>>> "nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

How can I write the string literal in my code?

Comment: This is covered in elementary Python tutorials: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: point taken, i didn't realise how simple a question that was

Comment: Anyway, +1 because the question is clear, and the answer is clear as well. So if somebody search this on Google, he/she will find it in seconds while it's not the case in the Python doc or tuto. Doesn't deserve a huge score, but a negative one seems too much for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply enclose it in single quotes:

```
'nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)'
```

There are several alternatives, such as escaping the embedded quotes with backslashes:

```
"nuke.execute(\"Write1\", 1, 10, 1)"
```

or using triple-quoted strings:

```
"""nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)"""
```

or

```
'''nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)'''
```

You can read more about Python string literals in the [manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes:

```
'nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)'
```

or you can use backslashes to "escape" the embedded quotes:

```
"nuke.execute(\"Write1\", 1, 10, 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotation marks using \:

```
"nuke.execute(\"Write1\", 1, 10, 1)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `'nuke.execute("Write1", 1, 10, 1)'`?